# How to enable the emmet in the eclipse

Tags: eclipse, emmet

I have install the Zen coding plugin into the Eclipse offline. But I don't know how to enable it?

I find some way to set the key, but I failed. I find the key 'Tab' but can't use it and I don't know how to change the key because I can't find the option of the emmet in the key configuration menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi if you see under Window menu -> preference -> General -> Key 
You can find all the sortcuts you need.

Ctrl + Alt + Enter

Answer (score 1):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> on a Mac instead which will work in all editors.